# How to read and write from a COM port using PySerial?

Tags: python, windows, pyserial

I have Python 3.6.1 and PySerial installed. I am able to get a list of COM ports connected. I want to send data to the COM port and receive responses:

```
import serial.tools.list_ports as port_list
ports = list(port_list.comports())
for p in ports:
    print (p)
```

Output:

> COM7 - Prolific USB-to-Serial Comm Port (COM7)
> COM1 - Communications Port (COM1)

From [PySerial documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/pyserial/shortintro.html#opening-serial-ports):

```
>>> import serial
>>> ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')  # open serial port
>>> print(ser.name)         # check which port was really used
>>> ser.write(b'hello')     # write a string
>>> ser.close()             # close port
```

I get an error from `ser = serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0')` because '/dev/ttyUSB0' makes no sense in Windows. What can I do in Windows?

Comment: Yes, silly me. Should have researched a bit. I can mark yours as an answer if you answer.

Comment: It's ok to ask for help like that when you've at least tried it as you did :)

Comment: Can you please keep that link shared to that you had earlier?

Comment: Its in my answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38790422/python-pyserial-reading-incoming-information-from-port?rq=1) could be what you want. I'll have a look at the docs on writing.
In windows use COM1 and COM2 etc without /dev/tty/ as that is for unix based systems. To read just use s.read() which waits for data, to write use s.write().

```
import serial

s = serial.Serial('COM7')
res = s.read()
print(res)
```

you may need to decode in to get integer values if thats whats being sent.

Answer (score 15):

On Windows, you need to install pyserial by running

`pip install pyserial`

then your code would be

```
import serial
import time

serialPort = serial.Serial(
    port="COM4", baudrate=9600, bytesize=8, timeout=2, stopbits=serial.STOPBITS_ONE
)
serialString = ""  # Used to hold data coming over UART
while 1:
    # Read data out of the buffer until a carraige return / new line is found
    serialString = serialPort.readline()

    # Print the contents of the serial data
    try:
        print(serialString.decode("Ascii"))
    except:
        pass
```

to write data to the port use the following method

`serialPort.write(b"Hi How are you \r\n")`

note:b"" indicate that you are sending bytes