# How can one read barcode from a barcode scanner using python

Tags: python, barcode, barcode-scanner, hid

I am in need of library that can read barcodes from usb connected barcode scanners. I have done my research but there happens to be one barcode api which was recommended which is https://github.com/libusb/hidapi hidapi but it happens to be written in C++ and I do not know how to use it.

**Any suggestion of alternatives to read barcodes from usb barcode scanners will be very well appreciated.**

Comment: Most barcode scanners have a driver that produces keystroke equivalents to the barcode scanned. This is at the OS level. You are reinventing the wheel to try and do it in Python.

Comment: what else did you find in your research? Your other results in research are your alternatives.

Comment: to be precise it is a datalogic gryphon barcode scanner please

Answer (score 2):

Many barcode scanners will hook into a PC as if it were a keyboard, and send through the text string as keyboard input when a barcode is scanned.

That would require no specialist library, as just monitoring keyboard input would be sufficient.

---

Looking through the [specifications](https://www.datalogic.com/upload/marketlit/manuals/gryphon/820050514.pdf) of your specific "datalogic gryphon" barcode scanner, it seems like there are some variants and drivers that allow this "Keyboard Interface".

If this is not working for your device, you can use the "COM-serial" or "RS-232" interfaces as input to your PC, and then use a library like [pyserial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38790422/python-pyserial-reading-incoming-information-from-port?rq=1) to read in the input of that stream.

---

TL;DR: This is a driver issue, you can probably get an easy keyboard-like input if you contact the manufacturer of your device. Otherwise PySerial is the library you are probably looking for.

Comment: You are definitely right when you said that barcode scanner often act as keyboards sending across test strings. I was just hoping to know if there is a way for me to know if the barcode scanner was triggered and capture the value and store directly in a variable without any any human intervention.

Comment: That depends on what system you are attaching the scanner to.
Is it a standalone system with the scanner as the only input, if so you can constantly be catching all keyboard input and treating that as barcode input.

Comment: Otherwise, if you also have a keyboard and other inputs, but want the python script to function without any human input, then using the Serial method of connecting to your scanner is the way to go. PySerial can be set up to listen on a port/com and trigger functions on input coming through.

Answer (score 0):

Connecting barcode scanners as keyboards can be problematic (security issues) or unrefined (scanning barcodes into incorrect fields). Here's a Python library that purports to bring barcodes in directly.

https://github.com/vpatron/barcode_scanner_python